# Add text chat to webRTC audio/video chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, chat, webrtc

I created an audio/video chat with webRTC using this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0), and now I want to add a text chat; I read about channels and I checked this [example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/basic/) , but since the example does not use sockets, I still have some questions.

Do I need to create another channel to transimit text? Should I use the same channel used for audio/video? If so, does this influence in quality for streaming?
Can someone tell me some guidelines to start adding the chat?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I added this code

```
function doCall() {
    console.log('Sending offer to peer');
    //create channel for chat
    var dataChannelParams = {
        reliable: true,
        ordered: true
    };
    var sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("chat", dataChannelParams);

    pc.ondatachannel = function(event) {
        var receiveChannel = event.channel;
        receiveChannel.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("ricevo questo messaggio: " + event.data);
            document.querySelector("textarea#receiveText").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    };

    document.querySelector("button#sendData").onclick = function() {
        var data = document.querySelector("textarea#inputText").value;
        console.log("invio questo messaggio: " + data);
        sendChannel.send(data);
    };

    pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
}
```

And I created two `textarea` objects, one with the send button and the other to receive text.
However, it works only in one direction: when I have 2 pcs on the same page, if I send text from pc1 to pc2 it works, but if I send text from pc2 to pc1 it does not. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the same connection, as it wont influence quality any more than a separate connection.

Just add:

```
var dataChannel = yourPeerConnection.createDataChannel("chat");
```

before you call `createOffer`, and there's your data channel.

#### Update:

Note that `ondatachannel` only fires on the end not creating the data channel.

Each data channel is bi-directional, so just add `onmessage` to the created `dataChannel`:

```
var dataChannel = pc.createDataChannel("chat", dataChannelParams);

dataChannel.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.querySelector("textarea#receiveText").innerHTML = event.data;
};
```